# Error while reading dynamically 2D array from a Text file in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to read 2 matrices from 2 different files based on the size the user enters to the program but i have an Access violation error.

I get the following error:

[image: error]

```
void main() {
  int **f = (int**)malloc(x1*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0;i<x1;i++)
    f[i] = (int*)malloc(y1*sizeof(int));

  int **s = (int**)malloc(x2*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0;i<x1;i++)
    s[i] = (int*)malloc(y2*sizeof(int));

  int **r = (int**)malloc(x1*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0;i<x1;i++)
    r[i] = (int*)malloc(y2*sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0;i<x1;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<y1;j++)
      fscanf(in1,"%d",&f[i][j]);

  for(int i=0;i<x2;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<y2;j++)
      fscanf(in2,"%d",&s[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you try to run your code under a debugger?

Comment: `x1, x2` definition missing.  Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Why does code lack a check for allocation failure?